# After updating Visual Studio to v17.9.3 the IDE closes and dotnet.exe command reports Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131506)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, ide

VS 2022 Community was running flawlessly for a month. Two days ago I was notified there was the update v17.9.3, so I launched it and left (I did a previous update some weeks ago with no troubles). When I was back the update was successful, VS told me that now I needed to log in with MS account so I tried but clicking the button didn't do anything! So I just had to click `Ignore for now`.

The IDE started but I saw some upper left error messages about not found main IDE functionalities. Then a MessageBox with the error `'VSPackage' not loaded correctly`. Rebooting the IDE didn't help.

I tried repairing VS, and even completely uninstalling and reinstalling it, but nothing helped.
I wanted to check my DotNet Core version, so I typed `dotnet --info` in a command prompt, but I received the message:

`Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131506)`

I finally succeeded in load and run one console program, before the IDE crashed, but in the console I received as output the same `Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131506)` message, so every error in the IDE depends on that dotnet.exe error message!

I tried downloading and installing the SKD 8.03, but same error.

I have 3 dotnet.exe files on my drive, 2 work and 1 not:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe --info
Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131506)

C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe --info
v8.03

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\dotnet\net8.0\runtime\dotnet.exe --info
v8.03
```

Opening the **Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022** and executing `dotnet.exe --info` I get the same internal error.

Concerning thing: I tried to install the Microsoft SDK 8.03 in a clean VM with Win10 and got the same internal error!

I tried repairing VS several times, even uninstalling VS and all the .Net related packages from my system, reinstalling VS from scratch, installing SDK .Net 8 manually, but nothing worked. I even tried the Enterprise demo version of VS.

I expect dotnet.exe produce a successful output with no error message, because the VS strange behavior depends on this.

Comment: The version in c:\program files\dotnet is 64 bit while the version in c:\program files (x86)\dotnet is 32 bit. Also VS2022 is 64 bit. That's the only obvious difference I can see here. You do run a 64 bit version of Windows?

Comment: 1.Sometimes, corrupted settings or extensions can cause issues. You can reset Visual Studio settings to their default values.
Close Visual Studio.
Open a command prompt and run the following command: devenv /resetsettings
Restart Visual Studio and see if the issue persists.
2.Visual Studio maintains a cache that can sometimes become corrupted. You could try clearing this cache to see if it resolves the issue. Go to %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ComponentModelCache and delete all the files and folders inside. Have you tried this update on other machines to see if it works?

Comment: I run Win11 Pro 23H3 64 bit. Yes, I tried deleting the ComponentModelCache folder.

Comment: I have the same problem, I think the problem is with .net version 8.0.203. I have tried if I install that version and use the command "dotnet --versions" it gives me the same error "Internal CLR error. (0x80131506)". If I install any previus version than 8.0.203 then everything works. When I install Visual Studio, it reinstalls version 8.0.203 and the dotnet commands do not work and Visual does not start. I've tried Winner1's solution and it works halfway. In my case I then have VS errors but Dotnet works.

Comment: Edit: I install 8.0.202 and same problem with dotnet commands. I will try with other packages or solution. Perhaps it is something that i don´t found yet.

Comment: Edit: Now i uninstall 8.0.202 and install 8.0.200-win-x64 and now dotnet commands working!!!

Comment: Edit: when i do "dotnet --info" it show "Not sdks installed" but show ".NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]", i think this is not normal

Comment: Edit: I rename a folder called dotnet in programs x86, then i do a clean of registry, and a repair of net and now ""dotnet --info" show the sdk installed. I will try now to install VS and see what happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem after recent upate,HostCrashException and package error,internal error etc , looks like its a version bug

try the solution mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78175128/8543147

no need to change the system dotnet at c:\Program Files\dotnet,it's done using a manual replace of dotnet that is being used by VS.this probably fixes your IDE crash problem and it seems fixing that CLR error is not neccessary for fixing the VS HostCrashException.

**Update:**
A tip was added to the mentioned solution about fixing that CLR error(based on [SilverBlack answer in that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78183392/8543147))

Comment: WOW! It worked for the VM where I had installed only the SDK 8.03 to! Now I'm trying on my machine with VS2022 Community...

Comment: Yes, I can confirm the fix worked even for VS2022 CE 17.9. But I had to replace the "8.0.3" folder with the  renamed "8.0.2" in both the following path:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\dotnet\net8.0\runtime\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App

If anyone have some issues, be sure to change the folder in both this path.

Comment: @SilverBlack glad to hear that it worked,i also updated my answer for this second path too,thanks

Comment: Anybody knows if has this issue been fixed in the just released v17.9.4 of VS?

Comment: @SilverBlack someone said that he had the same problem in 17.9.4 too

Comment: It seems to have been finally fixed on 17.9.5. It was an old CPU related issue.

Comment: No, unfortunately for me the issue is not fixed with v17.9.5 update. Yes, VS now starts up correctly, but compiling a console application results in this error:

“Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131506)”

Same error typing dotnet with any parameter.