# Visual Studio 2022 'HostCrashException' error after updating to 17.9.3 : Failed to start host 'dotnet.x64$IdentityHost' Host exited

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I recently updated Visual Studio 2022 (Community) to version 17.9.3, and now it no longer runs, I get this error:

> Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.HostCrashException:
> Failed to start host 'dotnet.x64$IdentityHost'. Host exited with code '-1073741819' (ErrorKind: HostExited) (ErrorKind: HostExited HResult: 80131500)

My OS: Windows 10

I tried multiple solutions recommended in both official and unofficial threads, like updating the .NET version, repairing VS, turning off antivirus, launching VS with custom commands, deleting VS ComponentModelCache etc.., no chance!

Some solutions helped to open the IDE,but just more errors came up, indicating that "Feature '...' is currently unavailable due to an internal error." and then IDE crash happened.

Also installing the preview version didn't help too,it just gave me another error AFTER opening VS indicating that the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.UserInformation` package did not load correctly(causing crashes)

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/could-not-start-visual-studio-failed-to-start-host/1170525

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, as its mentioned in question text, multiple methods from topics similar to that was tested it seems they didn't fix the root of problem.a working solution was posted recently. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the solution that worked for me but before explaining it i would say this method worked for v2022 **17.9.3** - Community edition, but this workflow may work in future versions too
(The original source of the method below is [here](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/686976598))

**Step 1:**
Download .NET Core version 8.0.2 **Runtime Binaries** from the link below:
https://versionsof.net/core/8.0/8.0.2/

**Step 2:**
Navigate to this path (update the path with your current VS path if needed):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\dotnet\net8.0\runtime\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
```

there is a folder with name `8.0.3`
rename that folder to something else, like `_8.0.3`(to hold it as a backup of the original one)

**Step 3:**
open the downloaded archive,extract the folder `shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.2`
from it and place it to the path mentioned in step 2

**Step 4:**
Rename the folder you got from tht archive at step 3 to `8.0.3`

now try openning the Visual studio again and check if its working

---

Tip: Accourding to [SilverBlacks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78175061/visual-studio-2022-error-after-updating-to-17-9-3-hostcrashexception-failed-t/78183392#78183392) in current topic, there is another path that contains dotent (like the path in step 2):

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
```

you can do the step 2,3,4 in that path too.
if you had the error `"Fatal error. Internal CLR error"` while using **dotnet command** in cmd or running project with **Visual Studio Code** (not Visual studio) , i highly recommend to try this because it may fix it.

---

**Note  1:**
Again, this solution worked for this specific version,if you face the similar problem in future versions,you may need to do the same thing but with different dotnet versions to fix it.

**Note 2:**
The [source topic](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/686976598) introduced a second solution,but to do the second method you must be able to open the VS for at least some seconds because changing something in options is needed.

**Note 3:**
If the mentioned way didn't help you,[downloading an older version of VS](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/) like 2019 , might be a useful temporary solution,because obviusly this error came up in new version and older versions might work.

Comment: Hello i had same problem. I did your solution and help to fix some problems with VS, but after this i had new errors and VS not working properly. Now i had all unistalled Vs. I am having problems with .NET. I installed .net 8.0.203 but dotnet --versions give error "Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131506)". In your case you solved all problems, are you having more errors?. What can i do?.

Comment: @NachoVazquezGonzalez hello, whats the error message after that change?in my case it didn't cause more errors but if you still get error i can recommend something: 1.if you can reach VS menu,try the second solution in the source link,its a checkmark in VS settings that may fix it 2.if it didn't help,try running VS as administrator. if none of them worked mention me here (for testing next methods) btw ,dont spend much time fixing that clr error,i still have it but it seems VS doesn't rely on it,one time i fixed that error but VS still had problems,so i think its not the main source of the issue

Comment: ok thank you, so you don´t fix clr error but VS works but you had some errors?, can you use VS?. I just fixed my error, i Post the steps i did in responses in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78170294/after-updating-visual-studio-to-v17-9-3-the-ide-closes-and-dotnet-exe-command-re", i will install VS now, and then try your method another time, perhaps now i have better results. I will return here with my notices.

Comment: Ok, i just install VS, now dotnet commands are broken another time. I don´t change anything of NET using your solution yet. VS start and run and i am logging. The problems starts when i load any project, VS start showing messages of caracteristc that fail and not load. For example "process telemetry, client listen async operations, etc" so VS not working. I will try your solution now to try to fix it. If i can´t i will contact Microsoft.

Comment: @NachoVazquezGonzalez yes after using that solution there was a CLR for using dotnet command (visual studio itself hadn't error ) ,its possible that the mentioned solution fixes that "Feature Telemetry .. is  not available" error too.Update: a tip added to the answer,it may fix the dotnet command error too.

Comment: i have all working now!, i wasted 5 days of my life but now all is solved. Thank you very much!!!, without help i can´t solve this!. Also i am noticed the nuget packets Microsoft.Maui.Controls and Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility vers. 8.0.7. are good but the new updates are causing errors!. For help some people that read this!. Have a nice coding!

Comment: i have samproblem with .net framework desktop project. how to fix this?

Comment: @nguyenmanh02123221 did you test the method?

Comment: Hi @Winner1, I downloaded the binary, copied it to 8.0.3 and renamed it to 8.0.2 but debugging in visual studio doesn't work.
Do I need to replace the `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` 8.0.3 folder?

Comment: Hi, I'm wrong. After copying, I still kept the folder name 8.0.3 but file of 8.0.2. win11-24h2/vs17.9.4 for vsto .net project but not working.

Comment: @nguyenmanh02123221 hi, did it fix the hostexception error? if you used the 8.0.2 files its ok and functions the same as renaming method, but i didn't test the debugging feature, try copying that folder to path 2 in c drive too, it may help. you can also try another thing : go to the link i mentioned as source and try the second solution mentioned there , then use the original 8.0.2 dotnet and test again

Answer (score 2):

This solutions worked for me!!! But I had to replace the "8.0.3" folder with the renamed "8.0.2" in both the following path:
Path 1:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\dotnet\net8.0\runtime\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
```

Path2:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
```

If anyone have some issues, be sure to change the folder in both this paths.

Comment: Answer is updated for that second path in drive C, i didn't know about that second path.  before this , VS was fixed but VS Code was still buggy because of that CLR error.now its ok too. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hi all  finally in think i got the solution for
Problem "Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.HostCrashException:
Failed to start host 'dotnet.x64$IdentityHost'. Host exited with code '-1073741819' (ErrorKind: HostExited) (ErrorKind: HostExited HResult: 80131500)"
then causes you can't start VS2022 my solution step here

- List item

1. uninstall All dotnet and remove dotnet folder form ..program/dotnet
2. uninstall VS2022 , for further installation
3. Download dotnet lasted Version of dotnet 7 sdk and install it
   3.1 i think Dotnet 8 miss something component form previously version in
   you don't have it may cause problems in Dotnet8 version
4. install Dotnet 8 and VS2022
   All work for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem was fixed with 17.9.5 version of VS, basing on what written here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-1793-crashes-during-star/10614986

It was due to using old CPUs like Intel Core2 (I have a Core2 Quad Q9550).

The 17.9.3 and 17.9.4 used an optimization instruction that is not present on old CPUs. New 17.9.5 checks if the optimization is possible for the CPU instruction set and if not it does not activate the optimization, resulting in a working .Net environment for both old and new platforms.